# Como posso fazer um número de tentativas no javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Estou fazendo um programa para adivinhar o número que a função random retorna. Mas não estou conseguindo fazer uma contagem de tentativas restantes para acabar o jogo

Segue o código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <title>Adivinhador de números</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    Adivinhador >:D.
  </body>
</html>

<script>

function numeroAleatorio(a, b) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() *(b - a + 1)) + a;
}
console.log(numeroAleatorio(0, 10));
prompt("Qual o número eu estou pensando?");

var tentativas = 3;

</script>
```

Answer (score -3):

```
for(i = 0; i<=10; i++){
   console.log(numeroAleatorio(0, 10));
    prompt("Qual o número eu estou pensando?");

}
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).